# Scala Source Code metrics : Cyclomatic or McCabe complexity, Halstead Complexity, Data Abstraction Coupling

Tags: scala, metrics, code-metrics, cloc

I am looking for a command line tool which calculates the source code metrics for scala language. I have seen some tools which generated metrics on the basis of loc(lines of code)& comments and I don't need this metrics(cloc,sbt-stats). I want a command line tool which can generate:

**McCabe Cyclomatic Complexity**

**Weighted Methods per Class (WMC)**

**Lack of Cohesion of Methods (LCOM*)**

**Halstead Complexity**

**Data Abstraction Coupling**

I have seen some answers which calculates metrics on on the basis of loc

[Scala source code metrics tool (lines of code, lines of comments and so on)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391537/scala-source-code-metrics-tool-lines-of-code-lines-of-comments-and-so-on)

but that link didn't help me! :( (Metrics on loc)
any help will be much appreciated ! Cheers!!

Comment: @stackoverflow please don't vote to close this as I have seen all questions related to metrics have been closed :(

Comment: It's not metrics questions that are closed. It's questions that ask for tools recommendations. And this is one of those.

Comment: Do you have a solution ? I need it urgently .. tried every link on Google didn't get much what I needed